# How do I enable ntpd to serve ntp clients (using macOS 10.14 Mojave)?

Tags: macos, network, mojave, ntp

So on macOS High Sierra 10.13, this answer worked fine: [How to enable ntpd to server ntp clients (using High Sierra)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324723/how-do-i-enable-ntpd-to-serve-ntp-clients-using-high-sierra?newreg=f2ef12ad4b38408a8f2d8ad3137d49ff)

Now I am running macOS 10.14 and they have removed both `ntpdate` and `ntpd-wrapper` (which was what the `org.ntp.ntpd-legacy.plist` LaunchDaemon was using).

**Is there a solution to configure a similar ntp relay with macOS 10.14?**

I am using a Mac Pro (Late 2013) which has 2 ethernet NIC's, and have one NIC with internet access, which is syncing to time.apple.com.  I need the second NIC that does not have internet access to act as an ntpd server for the devices on the private network segment that does not route outside it's private LAN segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the best solution for my situation.  I ended up installed Docker CE for Mac, then running a docker instance of NTP.  This achieved the desired results of getting an NTP service running on a the segregated network segment without having to have it routable to the internet.

[Docker CE for Mac](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac)

[docker NTP container on github](https://github.com/cturra/docker-ntp)

Answer (score 2):

From Macrumors (in the Mojave 'All the little things' thread):

Time sync: ntpd has been replaced by timed: not the old school unix one, but a new apple invention.

Have linked the timed Man page for ya:

https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/8/timed/

Comment: So basically macOS Mojave can only act as an NTP client, and can't perform any kind of NTP services on the network from the looks of it.